# Change only parts of a type in a C++ template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-conversion

Purpose and craziness aside, is there a way to achieve this in C++?

```
template <typename P>
void Q void_cast(P Q *p) const
{
    return static_cast<P Q *>(p);
}
```

I'm effectively trying to cast a pointer to a `void` pointer type whilst keeping any `const`, `restrict` and other qualifiers (denoted by `Q`).

I was under the impression there was stuff in the C++ standard library (or less desirably, in Boost), that allowed you to "tweak" properties of types, with finer granularity than say `const_cast` or `static_cast`.

Comment: Remember templates aren't merely textual substitution; some template parameter T could be int[3] and function parameter T &param would be a reference to an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you want `const X*` -> `const void*`, `volatile X*` -> `volatile void*`, etc.

You can do this with a set of overloads:

```
template<typename P>
void* void_cast(P* p)
{
    return p;
}

template<typename P>
void const* void_cast(P const* p)
{
    return p;
}

template<typename P>
void volatile* void_cast(P volatile* p)
{
    return p;
}

template<typename P>
void const volatile* void_cast(P const volatile* p)
{
    return p;
}
```

The new type traits are things like `add_const`, `add_volatile`, `remove_const` and `remove_volatile`. They work for transforming the cv-qualifiers of a type in a known way, not for applying the cv-qualifiers of one type to another.

Comment: You've identified precisely what I'm after, and explained how type traits relate to it. I'm still hopeful there is a less verbose way to achieve this.

Comment: @Matt: The only less verbose way is probably not to use a cast at all, because you can't capture the cv-qualifiers in a separate template parameter. Conversion to suitably qualified void pointer happens implicitly, and only a C-cast can remove the qualifiers.

Comment: Ultimately, I think these don't need to be templates. `void const* void_cast(void const* v) { return v; }` and friends are enough, I believe.

Comment: Possibly. The templates require a pointer, and won't work with a class that is implicitly convertible to a pointer unless you specify the pointer type (e.g. `void_cast<Y>(x)`) or cast the type to a pointer first (e.g. `void_cast((Y*)x)`), whereas plain functions will accept implicit conversions to the parameter type.

Comment: @visitor: I've removed the unnecessary `static_cast`s

Comment: How can you drop the static_casts? That was my whole reason for considering a void_cast in the first place: C++ doesn't allow converting to and from `void *` without casting (but C does).

Comment: In C++, a `T*` will implicitly convert to a `void*`, but not the other way round. cv-qualifiers must be preserved, so a `const T*` will implicitly convert to a `const void*`, but not to a `void*`.

Comment: @Anthony Williams: Never knew that (although I do it without noticing), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the boost type traits lib are some tools to remove qulifiers

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class From>
typename copy_rpcv<void, From*>::type void_cast(From *p) {
  return p;  // implicit conversion works
}
```

With a little [TMP utility](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/104d8782bb83/cpp/kniht/tmputil.hpp#cl-69):

```
// "copy ref/pointer/const/volatile"
template<class To, class From>
struct copy_rpcv {
  typedef To type;
};
template<class To, class From> struct copy_rpcv<To, From&        > { typedef typename copy_rpcv<To, From>::type&         type; };
template<class To, class From> struct copy_rpcv<To, From*        > { typedef typename copy_rpcv<To, From>::type*         type; };
template<class To, class From> struct copy_rpcv<To, From const   > { typedef typename copy_rpcv<To, From>::type const    type; };
template<class To, class From> struct copy_rpcv<To, From volatile> { typedef typename copy_rpcv<To, From>::type volatile type; };
```

You'd have to add another case for the restrict specifier; it probably would work just fine, but I don't know how it, as a non-standard feature in 03 (is it in 0x?), interacts:

```
template<class To, class From> struct copy_rpcv<To, From* restrict> { typedef typename copy_rpcv<To, From>::type* restrict type; };
```

My solution differs from [Anthony's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855378/change-only-parts-of-a-type-in-a-c-template/3855417#3855417) in preserving "nested" type info:

```
int *const *const p = 0;
void *const *const v = void_cast(p);
```